# CloudFormation Redis password encryption with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I want to deploy a password protected ElastiCache Redis using CloudFormation.
I'm looking for a way to set AuthToken in an encrypted manner to have it save in the codebase, trying to follow the infra-as-code rule.

Couldn't find a way of entering an encrypted password for CF to decrypt while deploying or something alike.

Does this option exist at all?

Comment: I am not sure if that is supported OOB by CFN. Probably using a Custom Resource? But not sure. Why can't you put the AuthToken in SecretsManager or SSS Parameter Store and refer that in your CFN template?

Comment: It seems like what I was looking for. I'll try this. Thanks!